# Assign value to Property by a value that is stored in an Array

Tags: c#, arrays, properties

I couldn't find my answer probably because my code is not written effectively and I'm probably making it harder than it is, but here is my situation.

I have a class (orders.cs) that has an array of decimal values (`decimal[] difficultyArray`).
In this class I have a property that returns the array (`public Array DifficultyArray`).
This class also has a property for the field (`private decimal productDifficulty`).

In my GUI I have a dropdown menu that has difficulties listed (easy, medium, hard).  When the user selects a difficulty I call a method to set the `productDifficulty`.  I am trying to accomplish this like this through the array/property ( i know the code is broken )

```
newOrder.ProductDifficulty = newOrder.DifficultyArray(0).Value; // broken
```

something like this works:

```
newOrder.ProductDifficulty = 1.0M
```

Index 0 in the array is 1.0M.  How can I assign the value in element 0 to the propperty/field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Array` is an abstract class and cannot be instantiated. Assuming that `ProductDifficulty` is a `decimal[]`, the following should work.

```
newOrder.ProductDifficulty = newOrder.DifficultyArray[0];
```

Comment: When I do what you are doing, I get the following error:  Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type system.Array

Comment: I see what you are saying now, but I think I get into more trouble if I change it.  My Proptery that returns the array is declared as public Array ProductDifficulty

Comment: What is DifficultyArray's actual type? That is, what does its initialization look like (`ProductDifficulty = new ???();` ?).

Comment: The array of decimal values is private so the only way for me to access the array of decimal values is either through a property or method.  I'm using a property, but I believe the property might be of the wrong type.  I have it as type Array and not decimal.  Should the property be of type decimal?

Comment: I would personally expose a `decimal[]` instead of an `Array`, but `Array` does have a method called `GetValue(int index)` that you can use - i.e. `newOrder.ProductDifficulty = (decimal)newOrder.DifficultyArray.GetValue(0);`

Comment: decimal[] productDifficulty;
productDifficulty = new decimal[] { 1.0M, 1.1M, 1.2M, 1.3M };

Comment: Thanks!  that way is working now wtih the GetValue() method.  I had that before, but I wasn't prefixing with (decimal).  I saw the cast error, but I wasn't sure how to cast it properly.  Now that I have this working, I'm thinking of doing your suggestion of exposing the property to a decimal.  That is what you are saying correct?  The field is decimal, the array of difficulties are decimal, but the property is of type array

Comment: Yes, I would just expose newOrder.ProductDifficulty as `decimal[]`

Answer (score 0):

array[0]

That gives you the item at index 0.  Assuming the object at index 0 has a property of Value, from there you can:

array[0].Value = 7;

If the array stores ints, array[0] gets the int itself, and can be assigned from there.

array[0] = 7

Comment: Yes element/index 0 has a value and that value is 1.0M (decimal).  I want to assign a field in that class to the value of this element/index.

I'm having a hard time figuring out how to assign a value at a specific index of the array to the field/property.  You can see the error I am getting in my previous comment